# Minimax in Tic-Tac-Toe not returning correct value

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I'm trying to write a Tic-Tac-Toe game and decided to use the MiniMax algorithm, but I'm having trouble implementing it. For example:
on a

```
  board = [
          "E", "E", "X",
          "E", "E", "X",
          "E", "O", "O"
          ];
```

It's the AI's turn and the function returns `AiMove { score: -10, coordinates: 0 }` as the best move. I've been trying to debug for quite some time now, but the recursive nature of the function and the amount of possible game trees, early game states in particular, are quite hard to follow and debug.

Could someone lend a hand?

https://jsfiddle.net/LdLqk1z8/4/

```js
var factions = {
  AIplayer: "X",
  humanPlayer: "O"
};

var gameResults = {
  winner: ""
};

var emptyCells = function(board) { //check for empty cells and return an array with the number of empty cells
  var indices = [];
  for (var itr = 0; itr < 9; itr++) {
    if (board[itr] === "E") {
      indices.push(itr);
    }
  }
  return indices;
};

var isGameOver = function(board) {
  var tile = board;

  //check for victory conditions
  for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i = i + 3) {
    if (tile[i] !== "E" && tile[i] === tile[i + 1] && tile[i + 1] === tile[i + 2]) {
      if (factions.AIplayer === tile[i]) {
        gameResults.winner = "AIplayer";
      } else if (tile[i] === factions.humanPlayer) {
        gameResults.winner = "humanPlayer";
      }
      return true;
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    if (tile[i] !== "E" && tile[i] === tile[i + 3] && tile[i + 3] === tile[i + 6]) {
      if (factions.AIplayer === tile[i]) {
        gameResults.winner = "AIplayer";
      } else if (tile[i] === factions.humanPlayer) {
        gameResults.winner = "humanPlayer";
      }
      return true;
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0, j = 4; i <= 2; i = i + 2, j = j - 2) {
    if (tile[i] !== "E" && tile[i] === tile[i + j] && tile[i + j] === tile[i + 2 * j]) {
      if (factions.AIplayer === tile[i]) {
        gameResults.winner = "AIplayer";
      } else if (tile[i] === factions.humanPlayer) {
        gameResults.winner = "humanPlayer";
      }
      return true;
    }
  }

  var check = emptyCells(board); //check if the game ended with a draw
  if (check.length === 0) {
    gameResults.winner = "draw";
    return true;
  } else {
    return false; //if no condition is matched the game has not concluded
  }
};

var getBestMove = function(board, player) {

  // return an AiMove object initialized to 10 if the AI player wins, -10 if the human player wins and 0 if the game is a draw
  if (isGameOver(board)) {
    if (gameResults.winner === "AIplayer") {
      return new AiMove(10);
    } else if (gameResults.winner === "humanPlayer") {
      return new AiMove(-10);
    } else if (gameResults.winner === "draw") {
      return new AiMove(0);
    }
  }

  var moves = []; //array to store all moves
  var currentPlayer = player;
  for (var i = 0, l = board.length; i < l; i++) { //iterate over the board
    if (board[i] == "E") { //if the tile is empty
      var move = new AiMove; //create new AiMove object and assign a coordinate
      move.coordinates = i;
      board[i] = currentPlayer; //update board
      //call getBestMove recursively with the next player
      if (currentPlayer === factions.AIplayer) {
        move.score = getBestMove(board, factions.humanPlayer).score;
      } else if (currentPlayer === factions.humanPlayer) {
        move.score = getBestMove(board, factions.AIplayer).score;
      }
      moves.push(move);

      board[i] = "E"; //clear tile after move is pushed in to the moves array
    }
  }

  //if it's the AI player's turn select biggest value from the moves array, if it's the human player's turn select the smallest value
  if (currentPlayer === factions.AIplayer) {
    var bestMove = 0;
    var bestScore = -10000;
    for (var i = 0; i < moves.length; i++) {
      if (moves[i].score > bestScore) {
        bestScore = moves[i].score;
        bestMove = i;
      }
    }
  } else if (currentPlayer === factions.humanPlayer) {
    var bestMove = 0;
    var bestScore = 10000;
    for (var i = 0; i < moves.length; i++) {
      if (moves[i].score < bestScore) {
        bestMove = i;
        bestScore = moves[i].score;
      }
    }
  }
  return moves[bestMove]; //return best move
};

var board = [
              "E", "E", "X",
              "E", "E", "X",
              "E", "O", "O"
              ];

function AiMove(score) {
  this.coordinates,
    this.score = score;
}

console.log(getBestMove(board, factions.AIplayer))
```

**EDIT:** Could it be that, since the board set up is unwinnable, and the AI is fatalistic, it "gives-up"? Would implementing the concept of "depth" solve this?

Comment: well, `isGameOver` thinks it's *game over man* - and, unless `O` is a poop flinging chimp, `X` can't win, `O` **must** win

Comment: Could you please provide a little more context, what does score: -10 mean?

Comment: @JaromandaX
Yeah, it seems the AI is fatalistic and assumes the player will not fling said poop and play 
perfectly which leads to the game being unwinnable. Thus throwing in the towel. 
I assume implementing depth - increasing the negative score with every recursive call, thus forcing the AI to block the opponents move even if it ultimately leads to it's demise - should solve this?

Comment: @BarneyChambers
The code is commented out/explained in the jsfiddle link I gave. It's just a run of the mill minimax implementation: forcing the AI to pick the largest value and the opponent trying to pick the smallest value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of introducing *depth* in the equation is indeed the right one.

Before doing `moves.push(move)` add the following line:

```
  move.score = Math.sign(move.score) * (Math.abs(move.score) - 1);
```

This will make the score 1 point less grave (-10 becomes -9, 10 becomes 9, ...etc). It expresses the idea that the further away a loss is, the less grave it is, and the closer a win is, the better it is.

In the sample board set up you provided, this will return 6 as the best move, which circumvents the immediate win of the human player. Of course, the AI will still lose against best play, as the game will continue like this:

```
. . X     . . X     . . X     X . X     X O X
. . X  →  . . X  →  . O X  →  . O X  →  . O X
. O O     X O O     X O O     X O O     X O O
```

For better debugging possibilities, I would write a function that prints the board to the console. For instance:

```
function printBoard(board) {
    console.log(board.slice(0, 3).join (' ').replace(/E/g, '.'));
    console.log(board.slice(3, 6).join (' ').replace(/E/g, '.'));
    console.log(board.slice(6, 9).join (' ').replace(/E/g, '.'));
    console.log('');
}
```

You could also look into making the code more object oriented, writing methods on a Game object, ...etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. That's quite an elegant way to implement depth. Actually, I had already written a simple GUI and game logic. I rewrote the AI code in jsfiddle in order to isolate other, unrelated, problems. Here's the full code as of writing: https://jsfiddle.net/LdLqk1z8/4/

Comment: Move all the code from `humanPlayerTurn` into `generateBoard`. See https://fiddle.jshell.net/w1cyxwhr/3/ for that update and a few minor other ones. Indeed, you should ask new questions via the  "Ask Question" button :P

Comment: I found the problem right at the same time you answered. `AiMove()` wasn't calling `humanPlayerTurn()`. So in games where the AI went first the game was freezing. But your solution makes more sense, there's no reason to keep calling `humanPlayerTurn()`, after each AI turn, and attaching the event multiple times (even though I do have a `.off()` function on game reset - to clear all the click events). Anyway, thanks for all the help.